# Sharing image from other apps unto my app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share

**When a user shares an image to my app from another app, I want to receive it as an image and handle it.**

I've already set up filters like this:

[image: Like so]

Now what I don't understand is how to actually receive the intent in my app nor how I could extract/handle an image from it.

---

I've tried googling the problem but no one seems to give a concrete answer on how to handle/receive the intent after setting up the filter.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the image uri in the activity like this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
                Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                if (imageUri != null) {
                    // Do whatever you want here
                }

            }
        }


    }
```

You can check the link for other mime types [Handle the Incoming Content](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html#handling-content)